# How does Lists in Python behave when the list item value has a space in between

Tags: python

```
list1 = ["Noki a"]
print (list1[0:3])  #gives ["Noki a"] as output.

print (list1[1:3])  #gives [] empty list as ouput.
```

i dont understand how this actually works. Need explanation on the same how the lists actually works when a space is there between the letters of a string present in list item.

Comment: You have gotten good answers to you question, but I wanted to add as a comment:  Why bother putting a single string into a list?   You can slice a string.  It doesn't have to be in a list.  `'Noki a'[0:3]` gives `'Nok'` and `'Noki a'[1:3]` gives `'ok'`.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with the space contained in the string. Your list has only one item at index 0 (the string `"Noki a"`), so slice [1, 3) is empty, since the slice excludes index 0.

If you want to slice the string instead of the list, you should index the string first, then slice:

```
list1[0][1:3]
```

Comment: Or take it one step backwards and don't even bother putting the string into a single item list--just slice the naked string, no?  (Not an objection to your answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Your list only has one element, which is `"Noki a"`. So based on slice notation, any slice including `[0]` will have that element, otherwise it will be empty.

If you were intending to slice part of your string, then remove the string from the list

```
>>> s = "Noki a"
>>> s[0:3]
'Nok'
>>> s[1:3]
'ok'
```

Or index element `[0]` from your list (which is the string it contains) then slice that result

```
>>> list1 = ["Noki a"]
>>> list1[0][0:3]
'Nok'
>>> list1[0][1:3]
'ok'
```

Answer (score 0):

To have a result where you are actually outputting the letters do:

```
list1 = ["N", "o", "k", "i", " ", "a"]
print (list1[0:3])
print (list1[1:3])
```

You currently instead have one item in your list so that is always the 0th item, meaning fro 0-3 it prints out the zero item, "Noki a", but from 1-3 it does not print this out.